# Why VBA code take longer time while execute

Tags: excel, vba

I need help to check why below VBA code take longer time while execute, its being more faster once test at first trials but now its take may be 10 - 20 mints although the data not more than 500 Row & 15 Columns

```
Sub Cell_Formatting()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "1" Or ws.Name = "2" Or ws.Name = "3" Or ws.Name = "4" Then
            ws.Select

            lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Range("A1:O" & lastRow).Select

            For Each self In Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                With Selection
                    .Borders.Weight = xlThin
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                End With
            Next
    
        End If
    Next ws
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you want `With self`?

Comment: If this code was working correctly, then there is no use of `SpecialCells` because it is irrelevantly used in a line which makes the code slow. If you remove everything but the *With statement* from the *If statement* and replace `Selection` with `ws.Range("A1:O" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)`, you'll get the same functionality but the code will be shorter, more readable and it will run hundreds if not thousands of times faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you need a loop over each individual cell:

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
   If ws.Name = "1" Or ws.Name = "2" Or ws.Name = "3" Or ws.Name = "4" Then
       Dim rng As Range
       Set rng = Nothing

       On Error Resume Next
       Set rng = ws.Columns("A:O").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
       On Error GoTo 0

       If not rng Is Nothing Then
           rng.Borders.Weight = xlThin
           rng.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
           rng.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
       End If
   End If
Next
```

Comment: Could you please explain more for each cell loop point to avoid it next

Comment: I was referring to the `For Each self` loop in your code. `self` is each individual cell, but you can just format the entire range. Well actually you don't even modify `self`, you modify `Selection` but you do it many many times.